# Are there any benefits of creating WCF service layer if Only one UI application will consume it?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I want to understand if there are any benefits of creating a WCF service layer for a asp.net web application, knowing that UI layer will always be asp.net web forms.

Comment: Who knows - suddenly, someone wants a Windows Phone front end or something.....

Comment: @marc_s: in that case, one can create the service when it's needed, according to the requirements gathered at the time (and not the requirements one guesses about ahead of time).

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend designing the "service" layer around a service contract, but not implementing as a WCF service unless required. This will make it easier to use WCF in the future if required, while not wasting your time with issues relating to networking and such, which you do not need at this time.

Comment: +1 excellent recommendation. Thinking about a service layer also helps create nicer, better separated layers in your software and eases maintainability and future growth